# OpenLayers3 WFS custom schema

Tags: openlayers, wfs, xml, gml

I'm having some trouble parsing the following WFS response into a feature:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection numberOfFeatures="1355" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.emsa.europa.eu/ais ./STIRES_WFS.xsd http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ais="http://www.emsa.europa.eu/ais" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
    <gml:featureMember>
        <ais:feature>
            <ais:MMSI>219009397</ais:MMSI>
            <ais:callsign>unknown</ais:callsign>
            <ais:name>unknown</ais:name>
            <ais:trackProperty>
                <ais:track>
                    <ais:objectStatus>
                        <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326">
                            <gml:pos>8.422975 55.475732</gml:pos>
                        </gml:Point>
                        <ais:time>2013-09-18T23:42:34.000</ais:time>
                        <ais:speedOverGround>0</ais:speedOverGround>
                        <ais:courseOverGround>306</ais:courseOverGround>
                        <ais:heading>244</ais:heading>
                        <ais:navigationalStatus>7</ais:navigationalStatus>
                        <ais:orderDetailId>127889</ais:orderDetailId>
                    </ais:objectStatus>
                </ais:track>
            </ais:trackProperty>
        </ais:feature>
    </gml:featureMember>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

Everything works fine up to the trackProperty, which is undefined in the parsed feature's properties. The rest of the properties (MMSI, callsign, name) all show up fine. So I assume the problem is with nested properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only support for simple features profile of GML right now.